# Which is much better/faster styling the layer in GeoServer or using Openlayers?

Tags: maps, openlayers, geoserver, wms

I have styled my layer in GeoServer using SLD, but it causes some delay like this one: [image]

This happens when panning and browsing on the map and I set the opacity to `.3`.

I don't know may be its projection, or is it much better to style it on client side using Openlayers?

Here's my code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',  {
            maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34), /*valid max extent for the projection EPSG:3857*/
            maxResolution: 156543.0339,
            numZoomLevels: 19,
            units: 'm',
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
            controls:[]
        });
...
        var floodMapCBR = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "Flood Hazard Map CBR", "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms",
                {
                    srs: 'EPSG:32651',
                    layers: 'cite:evidensapp_floodhazard',
                    format:'image/png8',
                    gridSet: 'EPSG:4326',
                    transparent: true
                },
                {
                    singleTile: false, 
                    isBaseLayer: false,
                    ratio: 1
                }
        );
```

Comment: The question is a bit too broad IMHO.

You should tell us more about the data, format, structure, preprocessing performed, what kind of style you are applying and so on.

Comment: The layer is from a PostGIS database; multipolygon.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of speed it depends on your machines (server side, client side and connection speed).

However styling on Geoserver vs openlayers is a matter of choice.
If you want to style on geoserver then you need to use the layer as wms in the openlayers. and if you want to style your layer in openlayers you need to consume the layer as wfs in openlayers.
Both options has their advantages and disadvantages. you need to decide on that.